# django show template based on date

Tags: python, django

I want to show certain template based on system date.
Let's say I have templates and models a, b, c, d.
I would be adding content to a, b, c, d separately, and I want it to show
certain template based on time of the day, but on the same html page(call it alphabet.html).

```
Template a on Monday. 
Template b on Tuesday. 
Template c on Wed. 
Template d on Thursday
but URL has to be on same html page. 
The contents/template would be shifting based on the date.
```

How should this be done? How should views, models, urls be set up?

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, in your views.py you just do an `if else` block:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def alphabet_view(request):
    if day == 'Monday':
        return render(request, 'a.html', {..context..})
    elif day == 'Tuesday':
        return render( request, 'b.html', {......})
```

`view_func` has only one url, but you could return whichever template you want based on the logic.

**Edit:**

Once again, you should refer to django doc. According to your comment, you should define you url like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^alphabet/$', views.alphabet_view, name='alphabet'),
]
```

Comment: You need to read the django basic tutorial first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views. One url definition corresponses to a views.py method, not a template name.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but what would be defining for urls.py?

Comment: I edited my question based on django tutorial and your question.

Comment: "Wouldn't this show a.html, b.html, etc.. on the url(127.0.0.1/a, 127.0.0./b and so forth)? "  No.  You need to understand a little more about django.  Your view is where you specify your template, your urls.py is where you provide the url pattern that matches your view.  If Shang Wang's answer is acceptable to you check it as accepted by clicking the check icon